# Automatically load comments when expanding post in flag queue

Tags: feature-request, flags, moderator-tools, comment-flags, flag-queue

When processing comment flags, my workflow looks like this:

1. Expand post
2. Expand comments
3. Delete comments
4. Delete/dismiss flag

Which has one too many steps in it.

For comment flags, there's basically no case where I would expand the post and *not* immediately expand the comments. The system should do this for me and save me a step.

More specifically, on any 'commenty' flag, expanding the post in the flag queue should automatically expand the comments. It should do this on all comment flags, the 'too many comments' flags, and any other comment-ish flags I'm forgetting about.